# Redirect 301 removing parameters in URL by .htaccess

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, .htaccess, redirect-url, 301-redirect

In the file `.htaccess` in magento, I want to redirect a url with parameters. An example is this:

```
https://example.com/presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso?PageSpeed=noscript
```

I need to redirect this to the same page, as in the example below:

```
https://example.com/presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso
```

In my `.htaccess` file, I try the following code without success:

```
RewriteRule ^presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso(.*)$    /presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso? [L,R=301]
```

When I use the `%{REQUEST_URI}` syntax it always redirects me to `/index.php` because of the particularities of Magento. Another way I tried was the following, but without success too:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PageSpeed=noscript$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso/?$ /presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso? [L,R=301]
```

I've been trying to do this in several ways, but all of them to no avail. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use two rewrite conditions - one for the `QUERY_STRING` and one for the `REQUEST_URI` and let the matching pattern be `.*` in the rewrite rule.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PageSpeed=noscript$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso/?$
RewriteRule .* /presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I put this code before the last rewrite of the standard Magento, in this case `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`, right?

Comment: Better as the first rule, right after `RewriteEngine on` then you have no interference with other rules